# Hiding CATiledLayer tile creation

Tags: ios, catiledlayer

Since in iOS5 Apple silently changed the tileSize limit to 1024. This limit has introduced a visual problem in my `CATiledLayer` in a `scrollview`. On Devices that have a larger screen size than the iPhone 5 you can see 2 (iPhone 5) or 4 (iPad) tiles when the screen is build.
While technically everything is OK, I think the user shouldn't see this process and should be presented with a fully build layer.

I already disable the fade duration, still the tiles are visible.

Problem: It doesn't seem to be possible to find out when `CATiledLayer` has finished drawing (threading, caching).

Any ideas on how this problem can be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to decrease the tile size. This may help with the visual effects when zooming and panning. Your next bet may involve preloading tiles before they become visible.

Comment: decreasing tile size increases loading time significantly (checked in Instruments).

Comment: That's good to hear. CATiledLayer is definitely a uniquely built class. I've heard of people trying to preload tiles also, but I haven't seen any examples so far.

Comment: increased loading time, wasn't meant to sound positive ;)